# Temporal Interval Event Support

Tags: events, wso2, complex-event-processing, temporal

I just want to know for sure if WSo2 CEP Engine supports temporal operators found in Allens 13 temporal operators and, also more clearly defined, in this article found online:

https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.2.0.CR4/drools-docs/html/DroolsComplexEventProcessingChapter.html#d0e10924

Even if there is no support or functionality for temporal events, are they pretty easy to code and are also efficient/easily handled by the stream?

I need to process multiple xml files each with its own dedicated stream, and each event has a start point and an end point and I want to flag these events when 2 or more occur at a specified point in time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although there's no direct one to one mapping between the WSO2 CEP's query language and the given list of operators, these can be quite easily implemented with it. WSO2 CEP's query language supports patterns, sequences, filters, windows, tables, joins and aggregation functions which are primitive building blocks for implementing such requirements. Hence you can quite easily implement all these temporal operators by putting together a combination of patterns/sequences/filters/windows/joins etc. Have a look at the Siddhi (underlying CEP engine in WSO2 CEP) [query language specification](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP400/SiddhiQL+Guide+3.0) to get an idea about the query language.

Also it comes with a number of event receiver types which support many commonly used transports and message formats including XML and JSON. You can extract data from an xml using xpath expressions and feed the resulting event to the engine for processing. Refer [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP400/Configuring+CEP+to+Receive+Data) on how to receive data.

In addition, if your use case requires writing extensions, WSO2 CEP has an [extension mechanism](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP400/SiddhiQL+Guide+3.0#SiddhiQLGuide3.0-SiddhiExtensions) which supports many types of extensions written using plain Java code and additionally, custom functions written using JavaScript/Scala and R.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'm currently using Drools Fusion right now for this task as it was a last resort. But it is giving me bother and is not well documented or supported. Cheers again!